# How to send a package to CTAN with ctanupload? (I get an error)

Tags: package-writing, scripts, ctan

Im trying to send a new package to CTAN and I wanted to use the makefile given in the manual of `ctanupload`. This is how my file looks

```
CONTRIBUTION = metrix
NAME = Tobias Weh
EMAIL = mail@tweh.de
DIRECTORY = /macros/latex/contrib/${CONTRIBUTION}
LICENSE = free
FREEVERSION = lppl
FILE = ${CONTRIBUTION}.tar.gz

export CONTRIBUTION VERSION NAME EMAIL SUMMARY DIRECTORY DONOTANNOUNCE ANNOUNCE NOTES LICENSE FREEVERSION FILE

ctanify: ${FILE}

${CONTRIBUTION}.sty: ${CONTRIBUTION}.ins ${CONTRIBUTION}.dtx
    yes | tex $<

${FILE}: ${CONTRIBUTION}.dtx ${CONTRIBUTION}.ins ${CONTRIBUTION}.sty README ${CONTRIBUTION}-doc.pdf
    ctanify $^

upload: ctanify
    ctanupload -p
```

Is saved this file as `makefile` in `metrix/`. I can run it with `make` and at least `ctanify` produces the `.tar.gz` file but then nothing more happens. When I try to call `ctanupload -p` directly from terminal I get this error:

```
Tobis-Mac:metrix Tobi$ ctanupload -p
Can't locate WWW/Mechanize.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at /usr/texbin/ctanupload line 434.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/texbin/ctanupload line 434.
Tobis-Mac:metrix Tobi$ ctanupload -p
Can't locate WWW/Mechanize.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at /usr/texbin/ctanupload line 434.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/texbin/ctanupload line 434.
```

I’m using Mac OS X 10.8 on a MacBook Pro. My TeX Live 2013 is as up to date as possible. My Perl has the version number `v5.12.4` (I can’t find out how to update …)

Comment: Looks like a perl package is missing.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Hm … any ideas how to fix this or at least which package is missing? I ran `cpan [1]: update` but it didn't help ...

Comment: @MartinSchröder: It works now, but when I use the makefile it seems to call `ctanify` only and then finishes …

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Do you have an idea why the makfile doesn’t (seems to) call `ctanuppload` but only `ctanify`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Martin pointed me to the right Google search :-)  The package `WWW::Mechanize` was missing and I could install it with `cpan` using

```
$ cpan install WWW::Mechanize
```